# Text through border in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add the text through a container border in flutter. 
[image]

I just want that Address to appear through a gap between the top border. It doesn't seem possible using a positioned widget, because then the border lines would appear through the "Address" text.

Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 11):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool isFocused = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    focusNode.addListener(_onFocusChange);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onFocusChange() {
    setState(() => isFocused = !isFocused);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 500, vertical: 300),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: TextFormField(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Address',
                    style:
                        isFocused ? TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]) : null,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As far as I know there is no way to centerized labelText in InputDecoration.

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be the container border? If not, you can use the TextField with InputDecoration like this:

```
TextField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: OutlineInputBorder(),
         labelText: 'Label Text',
     ),
     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

But Sadly the TextField dose not support the centered label text (`textAlign: TextAlign.center,` only centers the hint text). If you want to center the label text you have to change the `TextField.dart`.

This is `TextField` so it's not like a usual `Text` because it is editable. If you want it to be like a Text,set `enabled: false` and give a controller to it and set an initial value. Or you can use `TextFormField` so you don't have to use a controller. Like this:

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Address',
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    enabled: true,
    initialValue: 'Address Here',
),
```